# How to get OpenID user Profile info?

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid, openid-selector

After logging into SO, my nickname shows up at the top.

**When I set up openid on my site, I do not get any profile information.**

I tried implementing OpenID using [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) and [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html)

The response parameters I get:

```
openid.assoc_handle B2Jgsdf7jkDsdfUwWBGMHUshLmavymH...
openid.claimed_id   https://me.yahoo.com/MyYahooId#50a9f
openid.identity https://me.yahoo.com/MyYahooId
openid.mode id_res
openid.ns   http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
openid.ns.pape  http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
openid.op_endpoint  https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
openid.pape.auth_level.nist 0
openid.pape.auth_level.ns.nist  http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-63/SP800-63V1_0_2.pdf
openid.pape.auth_policies   http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/none
openid.realm    http://mywebsite.com/
openid.response_nonce   2009-10-28T18:23:05Zyj0aF9sdfsdfCmoegeAiQ--
openid.return_to    http://mywebsite.com/
openid.sig  U9O4UpuPsdfdsfsdfBHbVLdjiSyo=
openid.signed   assoc_handle,claimed_id,identity,mode,ns,op_endpoint,response_nonce,return_to,signed,ns.pape,pape.auth_level.ns.nist,pape.auth_level.nist,pape.auth_policies
```

**What is the reason I do not receive profile information such as nickname?**
When SO uses openid-selector, how does it get the nickname?

Comment: It has been a while since I registered, but I seem to remember having to pick a username...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any information aside from claimed_id and endpoint URL must be retrieved via Simple Registration (SREG) or Attribute Exchange (AX) extensions to OpenID.

You must explicitly request for them when asking for authentication.

Zend's consumer SREG documentation can be found here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.consumer.html#zend.openid.consumer.sreg

Note that these information are not guaranteed, and providers are given the freedom to decide (with or without user input) to withhold any and all requested information, or not support them outright.

Comment: Google implements AX as well as Yahoo (you have to request permission from yahoo). Unfortunately Zend Framework OpenID only supports SREG at the time of this writing but I've written an extension for AX support here as well http://ak33m.com/?p=71

Comment: I was using SREG but it did not return any info.

Comment: SREG and AX information is not guaranteed. The choice to provide information requested via these extensions is always in the hands of the user and OpenID provider.