# How to authenticate a user with Google gmail account like stackoverflow

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, oauth

I want to authenticate a user using Google account. I had developed oauth using some libraries.

But it is giving me a message like some website is **asking permission to access google docs/calendar/etc.,**.

**When we are logging into stackoverflow.com it is asking stackoverflow.com is accessing you@gmail.com. How can i get a permission for email address.**

**Update:** I developed oauth using Zend PHP library.

And see the screenshots

**stackexchange.com**

[image]

**My application screenshot**

[image]

Thank You

Comment: I thought everyone used this: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html

Comment: @Carnotaurs: this is related to google apps !

Comment: Are you sure you want OAuth and not Google's OpenID? There are not the same thing.

Comment: @Marcin: I am sure i want oAuth only. (not OpenID)

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, I'm working on example ZF 1.11 application that uses OpenID and openid-selector. The ZF application, called zfopenid, can be downloaded from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/someexamplestuffsite/Home/zfopenid.tar.gz?attredirects=0&d=1) (it contains full ZF library and it should work out of the box):
[image]
Authentication with google, yahoo works (at least for me) at this stage. To make it work I needed to make some changes in `Zend_OpenId_Consumer` described at http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6905 + some additional changes. Also I incorporated `My_OpenId_Extension_AttributeExchange` (i.e. AttributeExchange [implementation](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7328) by Chris Bisnett) to fetch email from google, yahoo (at the moment it is not displayed, but it should be in $_GET variable returned from google, yahoo, aol or myopenid to user/login).

So, if you or anyone would like to test it, I would be grateful as I'm planning to eventually write a blog post about this. Any feedback would be very helpful at this stage. Specifically, whether it really works, or it just works for me (I'm running it on localhost using XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a and Linux Mint 10).

Comment: you are the one ! , i had give it a try , i was able to ask google for (firstname , lastname , email )  , can you push it to github ?? so we can collaborate :)

Comment: @tawfekov. I'm happy you liked it. I just made a push to https://github.com/marcinwol/zfopenid. From library/Zend I pushed only Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php.

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiment with ZF to create OPEN ID login form , but i case of google , i was able to sign in but i wasn't able to ask google for the user info

because google is implementing openid extension called `AX` as i remember   ,   while ZF implement only `SREG` , you can find it in `library/Zend/OpenId/Extension`

here is my demo example http://zc.dagho.com/index/login , its working very nice with google and others but it can't ask for users info

and you can take alook to : [How to get OpenID user Profile info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639196/how-to-get-openid-user-profile-info)

> Google implements AX as well as Yahoo
>   (you have to request permission from
>   yahoo). Unfortunately Zend Framework
>   OpenID only supports SREG at the time
>   of this writing but I've written an
>   extension for AX support here as well
>   ak33m.com/?p=71 – Akeem Oct 29 '09 at
>   2:27

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6905

update : this might be good , i didn't test it : 
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7328

Comment: @killerFish , right now it doesn't ask the openid provider for the email , due the lake of implementation , once i will able to , i will push the example to my github account

Comment: Hi, if you are interested you can check my answer as it has an example with hopefully working zf+openid+google+AttributeExchange combination.

Comment: demo example link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

I believe Stackoverflow uses the http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ library.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56109/stack-overflow-and-dotnetopenauth

Answer (score -1):

you can authenticate users using google open id as in stackoverflow login.